# Granting access to outlook application

Tags: .net, outlook

I have developed a .NET application which is accessing outlook. For my computer it is working fine but when I am publsihing it and run it into other PC outlook is showing a pop up that "an external application want to access outlook, grant access for 1/2/5/10 min".

But my application wants access for more than 10 minutes. What will be the solution for this?

My guess:

1. How can I make this application as trusted in outlook?
2. My computer outlook never asked me about access why other computer want access time? Is this because I developed the application on my system?

**EDIT**

The same thing I found here http://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/

but When I am copying the code:

```
    AddinExpress.Outlook.SecurityManager SecurityManager = new AddinExpress.Outlook.SecurityManager();
SecurityManager.DisableOOMWarnings = true;
try {
// ... any action with protected objects ...  
} finally {
    // In any case please remember to turn on   
    // Outlook Security after your code,   
    // since now it is very easy to switch it off! :-)   
    SecurityManager.DisableOOMWarnings = false;
}
```

This stament is showing as error:

> AddinExpress.Outlook.SecurityManager

Which Namespace I have to use, I am using .NET 2.0.

Following are the namespaces I have already included in my .cs file

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Office;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using OutLook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Security;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning "Feature" is called the [*object model guard*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/1thd35d7%28en-US,VS.80%29.aspx).

Outlook 2007 will not popup warnings if it's running on a system with an up-to-date antivirus, so the other computer may not have an AV, or is running an AV that the security center API cannot interrogate for state.

If you're accessing outlook from a VSTO Addin you can bypass the guard by calling across the trusted `ThisApplication` object (example in link), if you're using vanilla interop you're going to need to do something else (E.g. [Redemption](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52)).

Comment: Thanks. I can understand now that why I am not getting any pop up in my computer, because I am using outlook 2007. But other coomputers are using outlook 2003. Is there any way I can disable that pop up for my application only ?

Comment: And the other problem is this I can not install any other software in other PC in which I am going to run my application.

Comment: Here is some info on mitigation for ol2k3; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168346%28v=office.11%29.aspx